# Tabulate Occurrences of Strings Across Multiple Columns in R

Tags: r, count, multiple-columns

I began with a string column in which a list of descriptive categories were comma-separated. So, for example, my original column contained observations such as "apple, orange, pear". I have since broken this to create a set of numbered new columns corresponding to the rank order of each descriptive category. Thus, the first new column contains the item that was listed as the first item in the series of categories. (e.g. "apple, orange, pear" was broken into column one "apple", column two "orange", column three "pear") The original column remains unchanged.

I now want to tabulate the total number of observations for each category across the collection of new columns. So, for example, I would like to produce a table showing the total number of "pear" observations, the total number of "apple" observations, etc. across the set of new columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simpler to get it from the original column:

```
table(unlist(strsplit(dataset$commaSeparatedColumn, split=", ")))
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked, once I had dropped the whitespace after the comma in the separator.